# How to adjust the screen animation speed of @react-navigation/material-top-tabs in react-navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6, react-navigation-top-tabs

I want to increase the animation speed. As I see in the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator, there is no longer props like timingConfig or springConfig in react-navigation v6.

Expected: Can adjust animation speed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems like there is no way to configure the animation speed right now, if you find a solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `@react-navigation` removed this option in v6. v5 had `timingOptions`, v6 no longer does.

The only explanation I've found is the following.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11173#issuecomment-1408886342

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35402673)